# tkinter attribute error in imported module

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a tinter GUI in which I use six imported self-written modules.I have linked two modules to a button and combine the output from each into an output in a label field. These two modules are identical ( bad practice, I know) except for the source of data that they use. The output is called by module_name.function_def(), but for one module I keep on getting :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'function_def'
```

If I open the module and load into IDLE, it opens the tinter GUI ( not sure why) and then the GUI functions as it should i.e. clicking the button displays expected results in the label field
How should I investigate this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The first rule of debugging is to assume that the error message is telling the truth. If you are getting `'module' object has no attribute 'function_def'` you must believe it to be a true statement. That means that either a) the module truly doesn't have that attribute, or b) `module` isn't what you think it is.

A simple first step is to add a print statement to print out what `module` is, immediately before you call `module.function_def()`. You'll probably be surprised about what it returns.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the print suggestion and got <module 'name' from module_name.py'> As I said, if I run the module in IDLE, it opens the gui ( for some reason that I don't understand) which then runs perfectly. The only thing that I can think of is that I import the gui into the module to get a variable that is entered in the gui i.e. I use gui_name.get(variable_name) Not sure whether this is necessary. Problem of having just enough knowledge to cause problems and not enough to solve them!

Comment: Why does a module not have an expected attribute. If I have a module named arithmetic that has a function 'def multiply()', why would multiply not appear as an attribute of the function? What errors should I look for? Not sure whether I am clear in what I am asking. I can import the module arithmetic , but give me an Attribute Error for multiply. If I do dir(arithmetic), multiply does not appear. Why?

Comment: You could be importing a different module than you think you are, or some code could delete the function after it's been created. Without you providing actual code for us to test, it's impossible for us to debug your code just by guessing at what you might be doing.

Comment: I will open another question with some code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Bryan, if you would, please answer a generic question. Why would a module have a specific attribute when imported into one file, but 'lose' the attribute when the same module is imported into a second file? What should one look for? Conflicts of name, imported same module twice...?